# CircleCI 2.0 -> /bin/bash: bash: command not found

Tags: bash, curl, nvm, circleci-2.0

In circle CI build I am trying to install nvm as follows:

```
  - run:
      name: Install nvm
      command: curl -o-https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash
```

But I am getting this error:
[image]

How do fix this issue?

Comment: Any help is appreciated

Comment: Most probably related to your $PATH environment variable setup.  1- Make sure you can run `$(which curl)` and `$(which bash)` from your command line.  If that does not work, fix that first.  2- if you can, then it is the environment in which your script runs (here it would be circleci).  3- worst case put the full path for both commands in your script.  That always works.

Answer (score -2):

*Disclaimer: Developer Advocate at CircleCI*

You didn't specify which Docker image (or executor) you are using. Most likely you're using a Docker image that doesn't include Bash. You can do one of three things:

1. Install Bash first in that Docker image.
2. Choose a Docker image with Bash already installed.
3. Use `sh` for the command instead of Bash.

Option 3 is the easiest option as long as the install script isn't using Bash specific features. You can try it by replacing the end of the command like this:

`curl -o-https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | sh`